# Mysql_num_rows в PDO

Tags: pdo, php

Здравствуйте подскажите пожалуйста есть такой вот код

```
 <?
      ///Начало вывода друзей
 $frnd_query = $bd->query("SELECT p.user_one,p.user_two,p.id,
                     u.username,u.family,u.avatarthb,u.birthdateDay,u.birthdateMonth,u.birthdateYear
                     FROM frnds p INNER JOIN users u
                     ON CASE
                     WHEN p.user_one = '$myrow[id]'
                     THEN p.user_two = u.id
                     WHEN u.id != '$myrow[id]'
                     THEN p.user_one= u.id
                     END
                     AND (
                     p.user_one ='$myrow[id]'
                     OR p.user_two ='$myrow[id]'
                     )
                     Order by p.id DESC Limit 10") or die(mysql_error());
 if (mysql_num_rows($frnd_query) > 0) {
    // Выводим полученные данные
    while ($run_frnd = $frnd_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

$user_one = $run_frnd['user_one'];
$user_two = $run_frnd['user_two'];

if ($user_one == $myrow['id']) {
$id = $user_two;
} else{
$id = $user_one;
}
      ?>
Не могу найти замену mysql_num_rows в PDO.Как можно подсчитать  типа если ровняется 0 то выводим нет записей если есть показываем.Помогите пожалуйста.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Метод ->rowCount() возвращает значение integer, указывающее количество строк, которые обрабатываются операцией. В последней версии PDO, в соответствии с отчетом об ошибках(http://bugs.php.net/40822) данный метод не работает с выражениями SELECT.... далее смотрим [тут](http://ruseller.com/lessons.php?rub=28&id=610)

Comment: @Ale_x Спасибо большое, уже разобрался.